# How to get value from a dropdownlist selection listed by another dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a dropdown list using another dropdown list. The issue i am facing is that I am able to retrieve the choice of the first dropdown list but not the second one.

Here is my **script** under view

```js
$(function() {
  $("#Off").change(function() {
    $.get("/Reference/GetSubjectById", {
      id: $("#Off").val()
    }, function(data) {
      $("#Su").empty() $.each(data, function(mail, row) {
        $("#Su").append(" <option value='" + row.Id_Subject + "'>" + row.Subject_Matter + "</option>")
      });
    })
  });
});
```

Here my **controller**

```
public ActionResult Mail()
    {
        fillingEntities db = new fillingEntities();
        ViewBag.OfficeName = new SelectList(db.offices, "Office_Id", "Office_Name");
        //ViewBag.SubjectName = new SelectList(db.subjects, "Subject_Id", "Subject_Matter");
        MailViewModel mailView = new MailViewModel();
        mailView.date = DateTime.Now;
        return View(mailView);
    }

    public JsonResult GetSubjectById(int id)
    {
        fillingEntities db = new fillingEntities();
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        return Json(db.subjects.Where(m => m.Office_Id == id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult New(int newref)
    {

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Save(MailViewModel mail)
    {
        fillingEntities db = new fillingEntities();
        //subject mySubject = db.subjects.Where(m => m.Subject_Id == mail.id_subject).FirstOrDefault();
        string subValue = Request.Form["Su"].ToString();
        reference lastRef =  db.references.ToList().LastOrDefault();
                 

        int numeroRef = (lastRef.Opening_Ref+1);
        //string referenceNumber = mySubject.Subject_Code + "/" + numeroRef + "/" + "2020";
        string referenceNumber = subValue + "/" + numeroRef + "/" + "2020";
        mail.NewReference = referenceNumber;
        

        reference newRef = new reference();
        newRef.Opening_Ref = numeroRef;
        db.references.Add(newRef);
        db.SaveChanges();

        mail newMail = new mail();
        newMail.Location = mail.location;
        newMail.Mail_Year = (short) DateTime.Now.Year;
        newMail.Mail_Date = DateTime.Now.Date;
        newMail.Addressed_Name = mail.addTo;
        newMail.Addressed_Department = mail.addDep;
        newMail.Addressed_Organisation = mail.addOrg;
        newMail.Mail_Subject = mail.subject;
        newMail.Reference_Id = newRef.Reference_Id;
        newMail.Office_Id = mail.id_office;
        db.mails.Add(newMail);
        db.SaveChanges();


        return View("Save", mail);
    }
```

And finaly my **viewmodel**

```
namespace FillingSystem.ViewModel
{
    public class MailViewModel
    {
        public string addTo { get; set; }
        public string addOrg { get; set; }
        public string addDep { get; set; }
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public DateTime year { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<office> offices { get; set; }
        public int id_office { get; set; }
        public int id_subject { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<subject> subjects { get; set; }
        public int Opening_Ref { get; set; }
        public string NewReference { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: sorry missed that part.. Here it is: <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#Off").change(function () {
            $.get("/Reference/GetSubjectById", { id: $("#Off").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#Su").empty()
                $.each(data, function (mail, row) {
                    $("#Su").append(" <option value='" + row.Id_Subject + "'>" + row.Subject_Matter + "</option>")
                });
            })
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: Don't post code into comments

Comment: Please add semicolons too so you do not get `$("#Su").empty() $.each(data, function(mail, row) {` when you minify or format

Comment: @JamesZ This is my first time, very well noted.